# Shrink a Dataproc worker boot disk

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

Due to some mix-up during planning we ended up with several worker nodes running 23TB drives which are now almost completely unused (we keep data on external storage). As the drives are only wasting money at the moment, we need to shrink them to a reasonable size.
Using weresync I was able to fully clone the drive to a much smaller one but apparently you can't swap the boot drive in GCE (which makes no sense to me). Is there a way to achieve that or do I need to create new workers using the images? If so, is there any other config I need to copy to the new instance in order for it to be automatically joined to the cluster?

Comment: Detaching/re-attaching boot disk to a VM should be a feature request. I would recommend you to create one using the '[Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests)'. While opening the feature request, try to include your use case scenario as well.

Answer (score 1):

Dataproc does not support VMs configuration changes in running clusters.

I would advise you to delete old cluster and create new one with workers disk size that you need.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up creating a ticket with GCP support - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120865687 - to get an official answer to that question. Got an that this is not possible currently but should be available shortly (within months) in the beta GCP CLI, possibly in the Console on a later data as well. 
Went on with a complete rebuild of the cluster.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/394800) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)